# Summing over columns using mutate

Tags: r

```
pixel230    pixel231    pixel232    pixel233    pixel234    pixel235...               
61           191         254         254         254        254  ...
0              0          0            0           0        0   ...
0            160         207           6           0        0   ...
23           210         253         253         253       248  ...
0             0           0            8         211       254    ...
```

I want to sum over cols skipping some in between and add a new column. 
There are actually pixel0 through pixel783 and 600000rows. 
Need something similar to:

```
mutate(df,eureka=sum([pixel230:pixel239]+[pixel244:pixel252])
```

How do I index the df to get this to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using `data.table`.  Specify the columns (`.SDcols`) that we need to get the `sum` ('nm1'), use `Reduce` to sum the corresponding elements of those columns, assign (`:=`) the output to new column ('eureka') (should be very fast for big datasets as it add columns by reference)

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <-paste0('pixel', c(230:231, 234:235))
setDT(df)[, eureka:=Reduce(`+`,.SD), .SDcols=nm1][]
#    pixel230 pixel231 pixel232 pixel233 pixel234 pixel235 eureka
#1:       61      191      254      254      254      254    760
#2:        0        0        0        0        0        0      0
#3:        0      160      207        6        0        0    160
#4:       23      210      253      253      253      248    734
#5:        0        0        0        8      211      254    465
```

Suppose if there are missing values (`NA`) in some of the columns, can replace it with '0' and do the `+`

```
  df[3,1] <- NA
  setDT(df)[, eureka := Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, function(x)
             replace(x, which(is.na(x)), 0))), .SDcols=nm1][]
```

a similar approach using `base R` is

```
   df['eureka'] <- Reduce(`+`,lapply(df[nm1], function(x) 
                        replace(x, which(is.na(x)), 0)))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(pixel230 = c(61L, 0L, 0L, 23L, 0L),
pixel231 =   c(191L, 0L, 160L, 210L, 0L), pixel232 = c(254L, 0L, 207L, 
253L, 0L), pixel233 = c(254L, 0L, 6L, 253L, 8L), pixel234 = c(254L, 
0L, 0L, 253L, 211L), pixel235 = c(254L, 0L, 0L, 248L, 254L
)), .Names = c("pixel230", "pixel231", "pixel232", "pixel233", 
"pixel234", "pixel235"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Did I mention I'm an R beginner. You lost me with your code akrun.

Comment: @mbs1 I added some explanation.  If that doesn't help, please tell me which part is confusing.  `nm` is the names of the columns that we need to get the sum of.  Convert the `data.frame` to `data.table` using `setDT`. get the sum of those subset columns `Reduce('+', .SD)`

Comment: I just read a short para on data.table package. Could you explain the "setDF" line of your code in detail? Is there a way to do this using dplyr?

Comment: @mbs1 You already got a dplyr answer from MrFlick.  The `setDT` is to convert the `data.frame` to `data.table`, similarly `setDF` converts `data.table` to `data.frame` Once, we convert the object to `data.table`, we can create a new column `eureka` by assigning (`:=`) it to the output generated from `Reduce('+', .SD`,  `.SD` means `Subset of Datatable`.  By specifying the `.SDcols`, we are only including those columns that are needed for the calculation.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `select()` to get the columns you want, then use `rowSums()` to add them up. For example

```
library(dplyr)

#reproducible example
set.seed(15)
dd <- data.frame(matrix(rpois(7*4,5), ncol=7))

dd %>% select(num_range("X", c(1:2, 5:7))) %>% mutate(eureka=rowSums(.))
```

This gives

```
  X1 X2 X5 X6 X7 eureka
1  5  4  5  7  5     26
2  3 11  9  7  6     36
3  9  7  3  4  2     25
4  6  3  7  2  3     21
```

To preserve all the variables, you can make a helper function

```
sum_num_range <- function(x, val, rng, name) {
    select(x,num_range(val, rng)) %>% 
        transmute_(.dots=setNames(list(~rowSums(.)), name)) %>% 
        cbind(x,.)
}

dd %>% sum_num_range("X", c(1:2, 5:7), "eureka")
```

which returns

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 eureka
1  5  4  6  5  5  7  5     26
2  3 11  7  6  9  7  6     36
3  9  7  2  7  3  4  2     25
4  6  3  6  7  7  2  3     21
```

or maybe more generally

```
sum_cols <- function(x, colspec, name) {
    select_(x, .dots=list(lazyeval::lazy(colspec))) %>% 
    transmute_(.dots=setNames(list(~rowSums(.)), name)) %>% 
    cbind(x,.)
}

dd %>% sum_cols(num_range("X", c(1:2, 5:7)), "eureka")
```

which should work with the other `select()` helper functions such as `starts_with()`, `ends_with()`, `everything()`, etc. See the `?select` help page for more info.

Comment: What does the (.) do?

Comment: In this particular instance, it just allows you to pass all the columns as a data.frame to the function in question. But `.` also can mean other things to dplyr and magrittr (where the `%>%` syntax comes from)

Comment: which library has num_range; my compiler is saying cannot find num_range

Comment: @mbs1 I've updated the new example. It should come from dplyr (see the examples on `?select`) but it seems it's not as easy to pass as a parameter as i hoped.

Comment: This is not working for me MrFlick. I'm getting an output but the sums are not correct.

Comment: The sums are correct in my example, right? So how is your data different than my example?

Comment: I just tested it using Excel. The way you suggested is just summing the entire row not only the digits I select.

Comment: Again, the sample code i've provided above works.  For the first row, i'm adding color 1,2,5,6,7. Those are 5+4+5+7+5 = 26 which is the value of eureka. So i'm pretty sure my code works. Either you are using the code incorrectly for your own data or your are not testing it correctly in Excel. I don't see an error here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward base R approach using rowSums:

```
df$eureka <- rowSums(df[paste0('pixel', c(230:239, 244:252))], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Edited to include `na.rm = TRUE` so you can also sum over columns that include NA entries.

The `paste0('pixel', c(230:239, 244:252))` creates a vector of those column names you want to use for calculating the row sums. Because you supply that vector to `df[...]` , the data is subsetted to only those columns for the rowSums, but all original columns remain in the "final" output + the new column.